# Create a journey builder via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

I'm trying to create a new Journey Builder from scratch via API using postman to send requests. Can you please tell me why this is not working?
POSTMAN'S BODY AND URI:

```
https://mcgy52s3ftpt5b-pl886t42g477y.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets 

{
   "key":"518002961",
   "name":"prova via API2",
   "description":"This is a description of my journey.",
   "defaults":{
      "email":[
         "{{Event.event-key.EmailAddress}}",
         "{{Contact.Default.Email}}"
      ]
   },
   "workflowApiVersion":1.0
}
```

POSTMAN'S RESPONSE:

```
{
   "documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
   "errorcode":0,
   "message":"Not Authorized"
}
```

POSTMAN'S TOKEN BODY (working):

```
{
   "grant_type":"client_credentials",
   "client_id":"xxx",
   "client_secret":"xxx",
   "account_id":"xxx"
}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, I have deleted the client id and secret - those are highly confidential, so please do not disclose them here. I can see that you're calling the `content/assets` route, not the interactions which you should use for Journey Builder. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: And not authorized tells me you have an issue with the scope of the installed package